# Why did this (ignorant) question receive such a poor response?

Tags: discussion

Today, a new user asked a [question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/65118/can-i-graft-a-pineapple-and-watermelon-together-since-the-both-berries) about grafting pineapple and watermelon.  That question currently has a score of -3, an accusation of being AI generated, and a bit of snark.  A poorly received question.

I see that the question is ignorant, but it also appears sincerely asked to me.  All the better, it makes for an easy answer.  I feel  *actively welcoming* new users is important on low traffic sites like this one.  That means accepting ignorant questions with grace. This site does not have the traffic to afford scaring anyone off.

Why was this question so poorly received?  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5):

I'm afraid I think its to do with ego - I think some members of the site believe people who ask questions here, on a Stack Exchange site, should have a minimal level of horticultural knowledge, and when their question displays they don't, they tend to ridicule,as if the OP does not belong here.  I notice the worst response in that vein has been removed, fortunately.
However, there are other sites under Stack Exchange where responses are even more unkind and even outright reject the facts given in an accurate answer. I don't agree with ridicule as a response to this particular question; we want people to ask questions even if they are ill informed, that's the way people learn and the point of sites like this, but, that said, other sites on here are far worse.